# How to make subst keep the prettiest name (minimum one in lexicographical order) in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The `subst` tactic is very useful in coq, it can remove useless variable names and make our context clear.

But when we have `a = a1 , a1 = a2` in our context, it often keeps `a2` instead of `a` in the result, which makes our context ugly.

Of course you can `rename` them one by one, but that makes `subst` not as convenient as before.

So I'm wondering, is there an easy way to make `subst` just keep the prettiest variable name, which can be just the minimum one in lexicographical order.

Comment: You can tell `subst` which variables to substitute for,  `Goal forall a a1 a2:nat, a = a1 -> a1 = a2 -> a + a1 = a2 + a1. intros; subst. Restart. intros; subst a1 a2.
`

Answer (score 2):

There's no generic way to analyze the names of variables in Ltac (without a plugin). If you generally run into this situation where equalities have newer variables on the right hand side you can write a version of `subst` that prefers right-to-left substitutions:

```
Ltac reverse_subst :=
  repeat match goal with
         | [ H: ?x = ?x' |- _ ] =>
           (is_var x'; subst x') || (is_var x; subst x)
         end.
```